# There is a way to show a video inside a webview instead of calling a VideoView?

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I'm trying to load a HTML5 webpage with a video tag and i want to display this video inside a webview. All of the examples i've tried calls an VideoView to display it. There is a way to do that without call the VideoView and display it inside the WebView? I'm using Android 2.3.4